# AWS Lambda hosted ASP.NET Core application with custom serializer

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I have an ASP.NET Core API hosted in an AWS Lambda. My problem is that by default every time the lambda is called, it automatically logs the execution context from API Gateway (`Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest`), and this contains EVERYTHING from the request, including the Authentication header with the bearer token. When the security team discovered that, they went crazy :)

To solve that, I read that we can create custom serializers by implementing the `ILambdaSerializer` interface. So I did it:

public sealed class AuthorizationHeaderMaskingLambdaJsonSerializer : ILambdaSerializer
{
public AuthorizationHeaderMaskingLambdaJsonSerializer() : this(null, null)
{ }

```
    public AuthorizationHeaderMaskingLambdaJsonSerializer(Action<JsonSerializerOptions> customizer)
      : this(customizer, null)
    { }

    public AuthorizationHeaderMaskingLambdaJsonSerializer(Action<JsonSerializerOptions> customizer, Action<JsonWriterOptions> jsonWriterCustomizer)
    {
        ...             
    }

    public void Serialize<T>(T response, Stream responseStream)
    {
        ... 
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(Stream requestStream)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` I set the serializer when adding Lambda Hosting:

```
services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi, options =>
{
    options.Serializer = new AuthorizationHeaderMaskingLambdaJsonSerializer();
});
```

But when the lambda runs, it seems the serializer is not being called because I still have the bearer token in the logs and I also cannot see some log call that I put in my serializer.

Am I missing any steps to make it work or this custom serializer only applies to serializing endpoint inputs/outputs?